# Good opportunity to add to your weapons library (Kickstarter closing in a few hours)

Tags: sound-libraries, weapon, gun

If you're wanting to add a few guns to your sound library, you may want to consider pitching in a few dollars to this firearms Kickstarter. Even a pledge as low as $1 will get you access to the full sound library. At the time of writing, there's a few hours and a couple hundred left to go in this.

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/bjjaszcz/the-firearm-sound-library

Yes, this isn't a question - but I thought this might actually be useful to a number of you here, so I'm posting it all the same. If this thing gets funded, it means we all get fairly cheap access to sounds that are expensive/dangerous/difficult to record. I checked the rules and I'm not 100% sure if this is kosher. If it isn't, feel free to let me know and close this thread.

UPDATE: The Kickstarter has finished and was successfully funded. Go us! ^^

Comment: This actually sounds like a really cool idea. It'll be interesting to hear the finished prodyct. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: Useful knowledge thanks. Kickstarter now finished so I guess we can close this one as off topic now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.